# Best way to merge JSON blob files to SQL table using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a bunch of JSON files coming into Azure data lake gen 2, the JSON files contains new data as well as updates.

The data needs to be merged into a SQL table so I can start to do some reporting. The way I solved the problem has been to create a Azure Data factory that looks like this

[image]

**Create and copy to temp table:**
First I use the copy data to take the JSON and create a table from the schema and dump the content into the table.

**Create delivery table:**
Creates a table with the right schema if it doesn't already exsist

**Merge temp with delivery:**
Here I use a merge clause to cast and merge the data from the table that was created at step 1 with the table from step 2.

**Delete temp data:**
Deletes the table from step 1

This data factory gets triggered each time there's a new file in the data lake.

The pipeline solves my problem but I feel like there's a lot of unnecessary overhead by creating and dropping a new table each time I process a file.

Is there a way to optimize this flow, maybe by merging the JSON directly to the "Delivery" table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider doing this with a data flow activity instead? Your source would be your JSON files. Add an Alter Row transform to perform conditional update, delete, insert, upserts. Then Sink is your SQL DB destination table.

Comment: When using the ELT pattern (extract, load transform), it's normal to have a staging table (what you're calling a delivery table). This would typically just be truncated>loaded>merged each time, not created and dropped each time. It depends on whether the table schema is identical every time or not. I see no problem with what you are doing.

Comment: The other advantage of using a staging table (that is only truncated at the start), is that if there is an issue, the data remains in the staging table and you can troubleshoot. This can be more difficult this option when using ETL pattern, as provided by data flows in ADF (extract, transform inline, and load). Also keep in mind that dataflows have a five minute warm up time and a compute cost.

Comment: Alright, thanks for input! 
I think I wanna try out a data flow activity just to compare the two solutions and get the some learnings.  If there really is a five minute warm up time and more compute cost then I would properly just leave it as it is.

Comment: For sure - give it a try and post back your findings.